# How to create a fulfilled promise in mpromise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have a node@4.3.1 + mongo + mongoose@4.4.4 project which I think is providing me with the mpromise library (the mongoose docs imply this)

Assuming it is mpromise, I'm stumped by the very simple job of creating an already fulfilled promise (so I can stub a function that should return a promise).

The [mpromise doc (see the "Chain" section)](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise) says I can do this:

```
function makeMeAPromise(i) {
  var p = new Promise;
  p.fulfill(i);
  return p;
}
```

But this fails with the exception "Promise resolver undefined is not a function".

Am I using mpromise?  Is the doc lying?  How do I create a resolved promise?

edit:  This works

```
return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) { fulfill("really?  this can't be the only way"); });
```

but that can't be the simplest way, right?

Comment: Try just `return p.resolve(i);`. Also, if you have `var Promise = require('mpromise');` then you are using `mpromise`, if not, then you are using something else

Comment: I wish I could...  `var p = new Promise;` causes the exception.  Same with `new Promise()`

Comment: try `return Promise.resolve(i)` @user1272965

Comment: Thanks. @BenjaminGruenbaum  Would sure appreciate the doc that fully describes mongo promises.  Just googled for 10 mins and I'm astonished about how much I didn't find.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, sorry to bother...Now I want to know how to do Promise.any(), but I don't want to post a bad SO question.  Can you tell me which promise library I am using, or how to figure that out, and where the doc is for it?

Comment: I don't use Mongo - that was an educated guess - you can ping me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript and we'll figure this out together if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo doesn't override the default `Promise` object in Node as far as I know. So the default ways should work just fine:

```
const resolvedPromise1 = new Promise(f => f("Fullfilled!"));
const resolvedPromise2 = Promise.resolve("Fullfilled!");
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Can you point to a doc on this?  docs.mongodb.org?